# Add a specific fee to the payment in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I'm working with magento2.1 I use

**Boolfly Payment Fee** extention for adding specific fee to the payment.
Link : https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee

but now I'm working with magento2.3. 
This extension is not working in magento2.3.
Please suggest any free extensions for this.

Comment: are you getting any error when you use this extension in magento2.3 ? if any then please post error here.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: yes... got an error. please check this link.  [https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee/issues/35#issuecomment-452613800](https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee/issues/35#issuecomment-452613800)